# Explicit formula of the solution of $u_{tt}=au_{xx}$ and for which values of $a$ is this a "wave equation"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Let $a\in\mathbb R\setminus{0}$ and $u\in C^2((0,\infty)\times\mathbb R)$ be a solution of $$u_{tt}=au_{xx}\tag1.$$

> I'm trying to
>
> 1. find an explicit formula of $u$ using the ansatz $$u(t,x)=v(t)w(x);\tag2$$ and
> 2. understand in which sense $(1)$ is a "wave equation" for appropriate values of $a$.

For 1.: By $(1)$ and $(2)$, $$v''(t)w(x)=av(t)w''(x)\tag3$$ and hence $$\frac{v''(t)}{v(t)}=a\frac{w''(x)}{w(x)}=\lambda\tag4$$ for some constant $\lambda\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and all $(t,x)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$ with $u(t,x)\ne0$.$^1$

The first system, $v''=\lambda v$, can be solved using the ansatz $v(t)=e^{\alpha t}$. We easily see that

- if $\lambda>0$, then $$v(t)=c_1e^{\alpha_1t}+c_2e^{-\alpha_1t}\tag5;$$
- if $\lambda=0$, then $$v(t)=c_1+c_2t\tag6;$$
- if $\lambda<0$, then $$v(t)=c_1e^{{\rm i}\alpha_1}+c_2e^{-{\rm i}\alpha_1}=\tilde c_1\cos(\alpha_1t)+\tilde c_2{\rm i}\sin(\alpha_1x)\tag7.$$

For the second system, $w''=\frac\lambda a$, we obtain solutions of precisely the same form by considering the cases $\frac\lambda a>0$, $\lambda=0$ and $\frac\lambda a<0$.

> So, the solution is finally a product of the terms in $(5)$-$(7)$ in $t$ and the corresponding terms in $x$. For example, if $a,\lambda>0$, then $$u(t,x)=c_1e^{\alpha_1t+\alpha_2x}+c_2e^{-\alpha_1t+\alpha_2x}+c_3e^{\alpha_1-\alpha_2x}+c_4e^{-\alpha_1t-\alpha_2x}\tag8.$$ Is there anything more we can do?
>
> And how do we need to approach question 2?

---

$^1$ I'm not sure how we subsequently need to argue for $(t,x)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$ with $u(t,x)=0$.

Comment: For question two, if $a < 0$ you have an elliptic problem (on the half plane) with no characteristic curves, when $a > 0$ it's hyperbolic with two characteristics. For the reference $^{1}$, I'm not really understanding the issue; if $u = 0$ then you you have found the solution and you are done (provided it satisfies the given data).

Comment: Here is a reference that you might find useful: [Indefinite double integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704186/indefinite-double-integral/1431425#1431425)

Comment: Initial conditons are needed with a wave equation. Where are they? Or do you just want a generic solution without the IC? Also remember that linear combinations (sums) of elementary solutions can be solutions as well. BTW, being a physicist by education, I do not understand quite well set theoretic parlance.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thank you for your comment. Well, initial conditions are "needed" if we want to obtain a *unique* solution, but we may clearly consider a "generic" solution of $(1)$ with arbitrary initial conditions.

Comment: @mattos Why is the problem "elliptic", if $a<0$, and "hyperbolic", if $a>0$, and how is this distinction related to the question in which sense it is a "wave equation"?

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been indicated in the comments, two different cases can be distinguished with equations of the form $\,u_{tt}=au_{xx}\,$
(apart from the case $a=0$). Without loss of generality (i.e. renaming of a variable and scaling in that dimension) we have:
$$
a \gt 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0
\quad \mbox{with} \quad a=c^2
\\ a \lt 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0
\quad \mbox{with} \quad a=-1\;,\; t=y
$$
In my [Indefinite double integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704186/indefinite-double-integral/1431425#1431425) answer it is proved with [Operator Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/operator.htm) that the first equation, the "wave equation", has the following general solutions:
$$
u(x,t) = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)
$$
Everything real-valued.
This can be interpreted physically as the superposition of a *wave* travelling forward and a *wave* travelling backward.

On the other hand, the second equation, an "elliptic" equation, has the following general solutions:
$$
u(x,y) = F(z) + G(\overline{z})
$$
These are related to holomorphic functions in the complex plane ($z=x+iy$) and they are of a completely different nature.

I think that nothing else is needed to answer the question as formulated in the header.

---

EDIT.
In the first place, one should get rid of the idea that a wave is something "oscillating".
In the present context it can as well be a bump that is propagating forward or backward. Or it can even be a standing wave,
as a result of the superposition of both.
Assuming that $a \gt 0$ the issues as described in the body of the question boils down to the folowing. Are the solutions as obtained
by separation of variables compatible with the general solutions as presented above: $\,u(x,t) = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)\,$? Let $\,a=c^2\,$
in what follows.

First case for $\,\lambda \gt 0\,$:
$$
u(t,x)=\left(c_1e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}.t}+c_2e^{\sqrt{\lambda}.t}\right)\left(c_3e^{-\sqrt{\lambda/a}.x}+c_4e^{\sqrt{\lambda/a}.x}\right) \\
= c_1c_3e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}.t-\sqrt{\lambda/a}.x} + c_1c_4e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}.t+\sqrt{\lambda/a}.x}
+ c_2c_3e^{+\sqrt{\lambda}.t-\sqrt{\lambda/a}.x} + c_2c_4e^{+\sqrt{\lambda}.t+\sqrt{\lambda/a}.x} \\
= \left[c_2c_3e^{-\sqrt{\lambda/a}(x-ct)} + c_1c_4e^{+\sqrt{\lambda/a}(x-ct)}\right] \\
+ \left[c_1c_3e^{-\sqrt{\lambda/a}(x+ct)} + c_2c_4e^{+\sqrt{\lambda/a}(x+ct)}\right] \\ = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)
$$
Second case for $\,\lambda \lt 0\,$, in very much the same way:
$$
u(t,x)= \left[c_2c_3e^{-i\sqrt{-\lambda/a}(x-ct)} + c_1c_4e^{+i\sqrt{-\lambda/a}(x-ct)}\right] \\
+ \left[c_1c_3e^{-i\sqrt{-\lambda/a}(x+ct)} + c_2c_4e^{+i\sqrt{-\lambda/a}(x+ct)}\right] \\ = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)
$$
These solutions are oscillating and real-valued, for suitable choices of the constants $c_k$.

It should be noticed that the above comes even closer to the general solution by considering linear combinations, resulting in expressions of the form
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_m C_me^{\pm\sqrt{\lambda_m/a}(x\pm ct)}
$$
where $\,\sqrt{\lambda_m/a}\,$ can be real or imaginary.

At last we have, for $\,\lambda = 0\,$, a solution that doesn't fit the bill:
$$
u(t,x)=(d_1+d_2t)(d_3+d_4x)\ne F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)
$$
No surprise, because the accompanying degenerate partial differential equations system can hardly be called a "wave equation":
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=0 \quad ; \quad \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0
$$
In an answer belonging to [Wave Equation by separation of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236696/wave-equation-by-separation-of-variables)
it is said that *$\lambda = 0$ is not a valid eigenvalue*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first part of my question is actually pretty clear to me now. However, I still don't know how to answer the second question, since it is somehow vague. The question is for which values of $a$ the solution is actually a model of a "wave". The basic solutions are precisely $u(t,x)=\left(c_1e^{-\sqrt{a\lambda}t}+c_2e^{\sqrt{a\lambda}t}\right)\left(c_3e^{-\sqrt{a\lambda}x}+c_4e^{\sqrt{a\lambda}x}\right)$, for arbitrary $c_i\in\mathbb R$ and $\lambda\ne0$, and $u(t,x)=(d_1+d_2t)(d_3+d_4x)$, for arbitrary $d_i\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Now, maybe what's meant is that if $a\lambda<0$, then the first set of basic solutions can be written in terms of sine/cosine-products. But since $\lambda$ can be negative or positive, I don't get how we "should" choose $a$ such that $(1)$ is actually a "wave equation".

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I've been trying to work out your comments in an EDIT of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. It's clear to me that when $\lambda=0$, the solution is not really a "wave". Regarding the other cases: It's clear to me that the solution is of the form $u(t,x)=f(x+t)+g(x-t)$. (In fact, it can be shown that $u(t,x)=\frac12\left(u(0,x+t)+u(0,x-t)+\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(0,s)\:{\rm d}s\right)$). You wrote that the solutions of this form are oscillating. Why is that? And what about the other scenarios (a bump that is propagating forward or backward or a standing wave) you've described? When do we encounter them?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Solutions of the form $\sum_m C_me^{i.k(x\pm ct)}$, when real-valued, are (part of) a Fourier series and hence represent functions that are periodic in $(x\pm ct)$ or superpositions of these.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Boundary conditions are involved with your last comment. I thought we agreed that these are beyond the scope of your question. As well as the "other scenarios": there are too many of them to fit into the margins of Mathematics Stack Exchange :-(